# JRibbon - How to place the the minimize, maximize, close button and title bar on top of the JRibbon?

Tags: java, look-and-feel, radiance-flamingo

I'm starting to create a Java Swing project using JRibbonFrame and JRibbon from pushingpixels. I noticed in the tutorial that the sample app containing the JRibbon is undecorated and the title bar, minimize, maximize and close button are placed on top of the JRibbon. Here's the link of the screenshot of the app : https://platform.netbeans.org/images/tutorials/ribbon/briefcase_16.png.

I manage to set my app undecorated, but placing the minimize, maximize, and close button on top of the JRibbon is still a mystery for me. How could this be done? Please help.

Comment: Let me say one thing why you don't go towards JFrame? JFrame of Swing library provide you all type of customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by applying different look and feel. In `WindowLookAndFeel` those buttons are display on title bar of JRibbonFrame, but if you apply some different theme (or if you say look and feel in java). this can easily done. Dose not required any other programming. source : [jribbon structure and simple jribbon program](http://www.pointbaba.com/blog/11/jribbon-structure-and-simple-program)